# Blazor session alternative

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I've done a asp.net framework app that has a login function (communicates with a sql server) and if the user logged in successfully, I would have stored the username in `Session["username"]`.

Is there a way to do the same thing(as in storing and calling) in Blazor? As far as I understand, blazor's server-side session alternative is stored for only one tab.

Comment: Your app should be talking to a server rather than connecting directly to the database. You are talking about a server side blazor so aren't you?

Comment: @peter Morris Yes, I am talking about server side. I am sadly not that knowledgeable about the proper usage of databases - I used sql queries and I am not sure if that is 'talking' or 'connecting'.

Comment: RE the DB: If it is server-side then it's okay. What is it that you wish to share across browser tabs?

Comment: RE DB: as mentioned in the main thread I wanted to store username in case user successfully logged in. A friend of mine suggested that I could use cookies but connecting to the sql server on each page load does not seem to be the greatest idea for me.

Comment: Try https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ProtectedBrowserStorage - instructions for use are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using authentication libraries that do this for you. Here's one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/microsoft-identity-web